# Why is compiler forcing me to use sorted(by:) in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift3

I am using Swift 3. I have a dictionary of arrays, and I am trying to sort the arrays in place using a property each object in the array contains.

As far as I understand it [as of Swift 3](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift3) sorted() does not sort in place, but instead returns a sorted array value. If you want to sort in place you should use sort(). But when I try the compiler keeps saying "sort() has been renamed sorted(by:)

Why won't the compiler let me use sort()

Here is my code:

```
func sortAllArraysInDict() {

    for arrayOfGrowthPaths in catDict.values {

        arrayOfGrowthPaths.sort({$0.growthPathDisplayOrder < $1.growthPathDisplayOrder})
}
```

Comment: just delete the parentheses `arrayOfGrowthPaths.sort{$0.growthPathDisplayOrder < $1.growthPathDisplayOrder}`

Comment: Awesome. Thx @LeoDabus , that worked.

Comment: @LeoDabus if you add it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you declare your array as variable and just delete the parentheses (trailing closure syntax):

```
arrayOfGrowthPaths.sort { $0.growthPathDisplayOrder < $1.growthPathDisplayOrder }
```

Comment: Not in Swift 3.

Comment: @JohnScalo yes you can Swift 3 or later. This is called trailing closure syntax.