# My Xcode is forcing me to use sorted(by:) instead of sort()

Tags: swift3

I am am trying to sort a dictionary. I decleared a global variable

```
var timesForRestaurants = [String: TimeInterval]()
```

Then I append the value in a separate function(recursively):

```
self.timesForRestaurants[restLocation.objectID] = timeVar
```

Then i call that in another function, and when I dump it I will get work. However, when i try to sort, it gives me the following error:

> 'sort' has been renamed to 'sorted(by:)'

I have already followed another StackOverFlow suggestion:
[Why is compiler forcing me to use sorted(by:) in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41295721/why-is-compiler-forcing-me-to-use-sortedby-in-swift-3)

And it works if i create a separate class to test, but the whenever i try and call it on my dictionary it fails.

Also, if i create a new variable, and use the sorted function, it works fine. Can anyone see why only when i call sort, it wont work?

Im using swift 3.2 and upgraded to xcode 9 today if that makes any difference.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot sort a dictionary. A dictionary is unordered by definition. The result of the sort function will be an array of tuples.

Comment: thank you, of course! So if i wanted to achieve the above (organise in order of objectID) the best option would be to make a custom class and then put them in an array? Also, if you make it an answer (or tell me where i an do so) ill mark it as such.

Comment: Yes, I would do that.

Comment: Great, thanks again that saved me a lot of time